# Sql relationships for a simple image upload system

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, normalization

I'm creating a simple image uploader system which uses four table `user`, `likes`, `images` and `comments`, in which users can upload, like and leave comments. I'm creating my tables in `mysql workbench`, and one of my table (witch count the number of likes of both comments and images)  has `one-to-many` relationship to both `images` and `comments`.my question is how can I deal with this properly? or should I remove the `likes` table and put `like_count` columns in `images` and `comments` tables? How can I solve this relationship between `likes`, `images` and `comments` problem?

users table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `user_passwd` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `activated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_registered` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `reset` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `users_pic` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_name_UNIQUE` (`user_name` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

image table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`images` (
  `image_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `image_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`, `users_user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_images_users_idx` (`users_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_images_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `my_db`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

comments table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`comments` (
  `comment_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `images_image_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `images_users_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `comment` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  `comment_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`, `images_image_id`, `images_users_user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_comments_images1_idx` (`images_image_id` ASC, `images_users_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comments_images1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`images_image_id` , `images_users_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `my_db`.`images` (`image_id` , `users_user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

likes table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`likes` (
  `like_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `like_count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `like_dislike` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `images_image_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `images_users_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `comments_comment_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `comments_images_image_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `comments_images_users_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`like_id`, `images_image_id`, `images_users_user_id`, `comments_comment_id`, `comments_images_image_id`, `comments_images_users_user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_likes_images1_idx` (`images_image_id` ASC, `images_users_user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_likes_comments1_idx` (`comments_comment_id` ASC, `comments_images_image_id` ASC, `comments_images_users_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_likes_images1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`images_image_id` , `images_users_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `my_db`.`images` (`image_id` , `users_user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_likes_comments1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comments_comment_id` , `comments_images_image_id` , `comments_images_users_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `my_db`.`comments` (`comment_id` , `images_image_id` , `images_users_user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image]

Comment: Why not have an image_likes table and a comment_likes table

Comment: @Strawberry I thought it was better just to have one table for image_likes and comment_likes.

Comment: i'd remove like count from the likes table, this should be calculated in images table and comments table separately or even better calculated on fly using count and group by. Your likes table should also link to your users table since it is a user that invokes a like. Should comments also link to the users table?

Comment: also, i don't think your comments table should store the image user, but should store the comment user.

Comment: since a user can only create a like for an image or comment once, you don't need the like_id you can use a combination of user_id and image_id/comment_id for your identifier